# Pandas DataFrame GroupBy by several columns with mean, StdDev and count statistics

Tags: pandas, statistics, summary

How can i calculate summary statistics (count, mean, Stddev) of ['Value'] column in data frame grouped by several other columns like ['Product'], ['Parameter'] and ['statistics']? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [describe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "a"], [3, 4, "b"]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  a
1  3  4  b

In [13]: df.describe()
Out[13]:
              A         B
count  2.000000  2.000000
mean   2.000000  3.000000
std    1.414214  1.414214
min    1.000000  2.000000
25%    1.500000  2.500000
50%    2.000000  3.000000
75%    2.500000  3.500000
max    3.000000  4.000000
```

Comment: Thank you, but describe grouped by several parameters, so default describe isn't enough

Comment: @Felix describe is also a groupby method.

Comment: Thank you, but need some kind of multi level index. How can i group by only by several columns?

Comment: That's what groupby describe does... ?

Comment: Is any other method besides describe()?